# Update the records if they exist

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

Periodically I need to check the records in a table and update them, in particular check the records with "`payment_pending`" status and update them to "`payment_pending_expired`" status. But I'm not sure how to do it properly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cancel_pending_orders(user_id integer, max_day_amount_allowed integer)
  RETURNS SETOF void AS
$BODY$

BEGIN
  -- if the records exist at all...
  IF EXISTS (
    SELECT ph.id FROM payment_history as ph  
    INNER JOIN payment AS p
    ON p.id = ph.payment_id
    WHERE p.user_id = $1
    AND ph.status = 'payment_pending'
    AND ph.added_at + max_day_amount_allowed <= now()
  ) THEN
    -- make all of them status = 'payment_pending_expired'


    RETURN;
  END IF;
```

The questions:
1) How do I add `max_day_amount_allowed` to `ph.added_at`? If it were a literal I could do this by:

```
....

  AND (ph.added_at + interval '30d') <= now()
```

but it is not a literal, it is a variable.

2) How do I refer to the found records (in case, the exist)

```
....
  ) THEN
    -- make all of them ph.status = 'payment_pending_expired'
    -- but how do I refer to them?

    RETURN;
```

P.S. `ph.status` has a type of `varchar` and not `integer` only for simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need to [cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) the day count to an interval:

```
AND (ph.added_at + ($2 || ' days')::interval) <= now()
```

2) You can use [`CURSOR`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-cursors.html)s to do something with each row in a result-set.

But in your case (if you want to only update them) just use a single `UPDATE` command:

```
UPDATE payment_history AS ph
   SET ph.status = 'payment_pending_expired'
  FROM payment AS p
 WHERE p.id = ph.payment_id
   AND p.user_id = $1
   AND ph.status = 'payment_pending'
   AND (ph.added_at + ($2 || ' days')::interval) <= now()
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do I add `max_day_amount_allowed` to `ph.added_at`?

Assuming the type **`timestamp`** for `added_at`.

Don't  convert to `text`, concatenate and convert back. Just multiply an `interval`:

```
ph.added_at + interval '1d' * max_day_amount_allowed <= now()
```

Or, if `added_at` is a **`date`**, you can just add `integer` to a `date`. The date is then coerced to timestamp automatically (according to *local* time) for the comparison to `now()`:

```
ph.added_at + max_day_amount_allowed <= now()
```